# What's the difference between proving Intersection of Sigma-Algebras is Sigma-Algebra and Countable Intersection of Sigma-algebras is Sigma-algebra?

Tags: measure-theory, proof-explanation

Does proving Intersection of Events is an event equivalent to proving Countable Intersection of Events is Event?

I heard that a sigma-algebra is also a delta algebra, so proving countable intersection of events is an event is trivial. Can I use the fact that because a sigma-algebra is a delta algebra, the intersection of events is an event?

*The following is proof that countable intersection of events is an event:*
$\\$
[image: Proof that Countable Intersection of Events is an Event]

[image: Intersection of Events is an event]

Comment: Your title is about intersections of sigma-algebras, but the body of your question seems to be about intersections of events. What?

Comment: @bof I thought an event-space is the same as a sigma-algebra.

Comment: In probability theory, a $\sigma$-algebra is a *collection* of events; the events are *elements* of the $\sigma$-algebra. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_space